# Error while setting up zookeeper php extension in order to install kafka-php

Tags: php, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, php-extension, pecl

I have an issue while installing [`kafka-php`](https://github.com/quipo/kafka-php). The zookeeper php extension is a dependency that I need to manage clusters.

I'm following [these instructions](https://github.com/Qihoo360/logkafka/blob/master/docs/install-php-zookeeper-extension.md) and I'm getting this error when running `./configure` after `phpize`:

> configure: error: Can't find zookeeper headers under "/usr/share/zookeeper"

I already verified that the path exists, and I also tried to install via `pecl`. That gives the same error (with other versions of the extension too).

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually zookeeper headers are on */usr/include/zookeeper* so I thing  */usr/*  is fine, as it is showed bellow.

To enable zookeeper support, configure with --with-libzookeeper-dir=DIR . DIR is the install prefix of ZooKeeper C Binding, which **must contain the include/zookeeper/zookeeper.h**

http://php.net/manual/en/zookeeper.installation.php